# Error due to single quote ' in javascript function call

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error

I am passing value dynamically to javascript function.

I am retrieving data from database and filling to javascript function, it does not have a static binding.

```
share_it(data_from_mysql_database);
```

like

```
share_it('value from mysql database');
```

Some times value contain a single quote (').

like:
    share_it(' Essentially you'll have to have a good academic history ');

So function call gives error that:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: before passing the string into function simply replace the ' with \' using regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You ought to be converting special chars on the upstream rather than the downstream. Converting it on the upstream saves time later when an inexperienced developer does not care to escape the data on the downstream when sent to the client. Since you have not properly converted the data on the upstream, you have no choice. You should escape it.

```
share_it(escape(data_from_mysql_database));
```

Example"

```
> escape("You're awesome");
'You%27re%20awesome'
>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the DB shouldn't store apostrophes or single quotes in case someone wants to output some data as a JS string literal? Also, what's with the %xx escaping in the JS string? Shouldn't you escape it with a \ instead?

Comment: The `escape` function is meant for encoding url parameter values. It's not meant for turning raw text into JS string literals. With this function, his code will _run_ but it won't work properly. The proper solution is to replace all ' or " with \' or \". Yes it needs to be done "manually" whenever he writes raw data to JS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\` character to *escape* such characters:

```
share_it(' Essentially you\'ll have to have a good past academic ');
```

Or, you can switch to using double quotes if you know you will need to embed a single quote character:

```
share_it(" Essentially you'll have to have a good past academic ");
```

Comment: i am passing value dynamically from database

Comment: @HiteshModha If you mean that you are building JavaScript code dynamically, then you will need to process the string yourself to add the required escape characters.  How you accomplish this depends on the language you are using to build the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can freely switch between double `"` and single `'` quotes where you need the *other* in a literal string:

```
share_it(" Essentially you'll have to have a good past academic ");
```

Only in cases where you need both, you need to escape the repeating character:

```
share_it(" Essentially you'll have to have a good \"past\" academic ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace the ' in the string with &#39.